# Ruby Scripting Mysql array 2D for dashing Widgets

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I've been struggling with this for almost two weeks now and I hope someone may help me out on how to convert my sql query from mysql db into 2D array for sending into the google charts widgets in dashing please?

My actual .rb script (Job) does this >

```
require 'mysql2'

SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  points = []

  # Mysql connection
  db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "192.168.xx.xx", :username => "xxxx", :password => "xxxxxx", :port => 3306, :database => "xxxxxx" )

  # Mysql query
  sql = "SELECT * FROM Table"
  ###Field 1 is Integer
  ###Field 2 is Decimal(65,30)

  rs = db.query(sql, :as => :array)

  subpoints = []

  subpoints.push('Week')

  subpoints.push('MTV')

  points.push(subpoints)

  rs.each do |row|

    subpoints = []

    subpoints.push(row['Field 1'])

    subpoints.push(row['Field 2'])

    points.push(subpoints)

  end

  ###Update the List widget
  send_event('mychart01', points: points)

  Mysql2.close

end
```

I get the error:

```
./mysql_chart_01.rb:23:in []': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) from ./mysql_chart_01.rb:23:inblock in '
from ./mysql_chart_01.rb:21:in each' from ./mysql_chart_01.rb:21:in'
```

Actually I'm not even sure to be able to make it work this way. Does anyone has a better suggestion or a Ruby script for Google charts?

Best regards.

Comment: my array should look like this

send_event('mychart', points: [
      ['Week', 'MTV'],
      ['29',  1000],
      ['30',  1170],
      ['31',  660],
      ['32',  1030]
  ])

Where 1st array should contain the header

Comment: This `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` error usually appear when you try to retrieve an element from an array using an non-integer index. Take a look at this http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com/2016/06/implicit-and-bad-type-conversion-example.html